# Does ExceptionMapper of RESTeasy scans all the modules in a Java EE application?

Tags: jakarta-ee, exception, jboss7.x, resteasy

I have a `Java EE` application running on `JBoss server`.
I have one `jar` where I defined all the exception classes and corresponding `ExceptionMappers` (implementing `ExceptionMapper` provided by `RESTeasy`)

For example, here is one:

```
@Provider
public class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyException>{


    protected Response toResponse(MyException e) {
        Log.info("Mapping exception to response for: " + e);
    }
}
```

These exceptions and their mappers are packaged into a single `jar`.

Now I have other modules (both `EJB` and `web` ) that uses this `jar` as dependency. These modules throw `Exceptions` that are defined in the dependent jar.

I have the following enabled in each of my EJB and web module that uses this dependency jar.

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

1)  The question is, does the exceptions thrown in my EJB or Web modules gets mapped.

2)  when I have the above `<context-param>`, does it scan the entire EE application or just one module

3) should I have to repeat the above `<context-param>` in all the modules that uses the exception dependency jar. or will defining it one place, will scan the entire application and keep a "note" of it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

1) The context should load your `@Provider` annotations and get mapped

2) It does scan the entire EE application

3) No, you just need it in the parent project `web.xml`.

Comment: I did not understand your 1st point. please elaborate if you can